# Azure API Management - Liquid Transformation does no longer work

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-api-management

I have several operations in Azure API Management which uses the liquid template.
A few weeks ago I recognized that existing liquid templates stopped working.

Did I something wrong? Is there an issue with API Management?
Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody) I'm not able to find any errors.

Therefore I created a basic example that does not transform the request body.

Policy:

```
    <policies>
        <inbound>
            <base />
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
                <set-body template="liquid">
                    {   
                    "email":"{{body.EmailAddress}}"
                    }
                </set-body>
            </return-response>
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <base />
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>
```

Request:

```
POST https://hidden.azure-api.net/evaluation/mm/liquid HTTP/1.1
Host: hidden.azure-api.net
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

{
    "EmailAddress": "sample@lorem.ipsum"
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

content-length: 79
date: Wed, 10 Feb 2021 07:50:53 GMT
vary: Origin

{   
   "email":""
}
```

My expectation is transformed body:

```
{   
   "email":"sample@lorem.ipsum"
}
```

Comment: I also had this once - let me think / look

Comment: So you want to directly respond with elements of the body which is coming with the request? Or do you plan to move this to <outbound/> later?

Comment: @KaiWalter There a several different APIs. So I need inbound and/or outbound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Support informed me that the *set-body* policy with liquid template is not supported in *return-response* policy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the `Content-Type: application/json` header to your request?
Liquid only works if the content type is set, else it couldn't know how to parse the document properly.

Comment: This didn't change anything