# Liquid body inside the return response policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Does anyone know how to access the request body from inside the <set-body template = "liquid"> statement when using the <return response> policy?
When I do like this the body seem to be empty:

```xml
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body template="liquid">
            {
            "name":"{{body.firstname}}"
            }
            
        </set-body>
    </return-response>
</inbound>
```

The request body is:

```json
{"firstname" : "John Doe"}`
```

Expected result would be:

```json
{"name":"John Doe"}
```

The result is:

```json
{"name":""}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft support told me that the policy `return-response` [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66434591/6886501) `set-body` with liquid template.

You can do a workaround by modifying the body before using it in `return-response`.

Inbound policy:

```xml
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-body template="liquid">
{
   "name":"{{body.firstname}}"
}
    </set-body>
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@{   
            string body = context.Request.Body.As<string>(true);
            return body;
        }</set-body>
    </return-response>
</inbound>
```

Request:

```
POST https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/sample/liquid HTTP/1.1
Host: rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net
Content-Type: application/json

{"firstname" : "John Doe"}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 35
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 09 Jan 2023 04:21:51 GMT
request-context: appId=cid-v1:a10dc7c9-c354-40a2-acf3-1401681f7808
vary: Origin

{
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

[image]